# What is the range of $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{|x|-|y|}$?

Tags: calculus, functions

I'd like  to find the range of the following function

> $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{|x|-|y|}$

Could someone help me? thanks

Comment: Actually, this question cannot be answered unequivocally without knowing what the domain of $f$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0$ take $x=0$ and $y=1$
For $>0$ take $x=2k$ and $y=k$ where $k>0$
For $<0$ take $x=-2k$ and $y=k$ where $k>0$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equation
$$
z=\frac{x}{x-1},\quad x>0
$$
that becomes
$$
x=\frac{z}{z-1}
$$
which has solutions for $z<0$ or $z>1$.

The equation
$$
z=\frac{x}{-x-1}\quad x<0
$$
becomes
$$
x=\frac{-z}{1+z}
$$
which has solutions for $z<-1$ or $z>0$.

Both equations correspond to $y=1$. Does $0$ belong to the range?